# Dynamically created views: Populate property metadata to nested view for client side validation?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have implemented a base view model for the configuration forms of different modules in my system.

In that base logic I'm iterating the reflected properties of the (user-)derived viewmodel and dynamically create a list of ConfigItem objects

Simplified my object looks as follows:

```
public class ConfigItem
{ 
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public object Value { get; set; }
     public  Type PropertyType { get; set; } 
     public ConfigType ConfigType { get; set; }
     public string PostId { get; set; } 
};
```

The "value" property can be an object of a simple or complex type (string, bool image, etc.).

In a nested view I'm rendering all ConfigItems in a loop (in order to decorate each with additional information like tooltips etc.).
For the binding of the posted form I'm setting the name attribute of the input fields so the values are bound back to the original's viewmodel properties. The validation of DataAnnotation attributes works on server-side.

**Now to the problem:**

As we all know ASP comes with the neat feature of rendering jquery unobtrusive validation attributes. Unfortunately I'm losing all my metadata when rendering ConfigItems instead of the original properties, thus ASP doesn't know about my attributes like e.g. "Required" or "StringLength". Does anyone have an idea how to somehow "carry-along" the property metadata?

The best thing would be that my ConfigItem's value could be an expression tree like of type Expression>, so I could carry along a "pointer" to the original property. But I couldn't figure out how to technically solve it. If someone could shed a little light on this (or perhaps have some other hints) I highly appreciate that. Thanks!

Update:
I'm rendering my ConfigItems with a little custom Html-Helper, where I evaluate the model state:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ConfigItem<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, ConfigItem configItem, bool isEditMode = false)
    {
        if (isEditMode)
        {
            if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(configItem.PostId))
            {
                var itemState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[configItem.PostId];

                if (itemState.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    configItem.ValidationMessage = string.Join("</br>", Array.ConvertAll(itemState.Errors.ToArray(), i => i.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
            return htmlHelper.Partial(EditorConfigItemPartialPath, configItem);
        }
        else
        {
            return htmlHelper.Partial(DisplayConfigItemPartialPath, configItem);
        }
    }
```

The ConfigItem EditorTemplate does something like this:

```
@model ConfigItem    
<div class="value">
@switch (Model.DataType)
{
    case ConfigDataType.String:
        {
            var value = Model.Value == null ? "" : Model.Value;
            @Html.EditorFor(m => value, "string", Model.PostId)
            break;
        }
    case ConfigDataType.Bool:
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Value, "", Model.PostId)
            break;
        }
    case ConfigDataType.Image:
        {
            @Html.ConfigImage(Model.Key, m => Model.Value, Url.Action(ApplicationController.ActionUploadImage), Model.PostId)
            break;
        }
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ValidationMessage))
{
    <span class="@errorClass">
        @Html.Raw(Model.ValidationMessage)
    </span>
}
</div>
```

Comment: how you are rendering ConfigItems ? Via JQuery AJAX or by your Code only ?

Comment: I updated my question for further clarification.

Comment: so you  lost your scripts at your partial view, Right ?

Comment: Exactly, I lost all the property metadata when setting their values to the config item "objects". I also tried a custom ModelValidatorProvider, but there' I'm not able to conclude from the "object" back to the view models original property.

Answer (score 0):

If your missing your Script your partial view, you can use below code:

**Common function for loading script into partial view :**

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

and call this function into your switch statement like below :

```
@switch (Model.DataType)
{
    case ConfigDataType.String:
        {
            var value = Model.Value == null ? "" : Model.Value;
            @Html.EditorFor(m => value, "string", Model.PostId)
            loadScript("~/Content/js/register.js", function(){
            //initialization code
            });
            break;
        }
    case ConfigDataType.Bool:
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Value, "", Model.PostId)
            loadScript("~/Content/js/register.js", function(){
            //initialization code
            });
            break;
        }
    case ConfigDataType.Image:
        {
            @Html.ConfigImage(Model.Key, m => Model.Value, Url.Action(ApplicationController.ActionUploadImage), Model.PostId)
            loadScript("~/Content/js/register.js", function(){
            //initialization code
            });
            break;
        }
}
```

replace `~/Content/js/register.js` with your required JavaScript

hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's a nice technique for loading scripts. But I don't want to mess with js there and instead use the mvc features which generate the right html attributes. If my viewmodel property has defined a [Required] attribute I want my helpers to automatically generate a html attribte aria-required="true". Therefore the helpers need the correct model/property context.
I appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: I think these attribute is already is there, Only you are not getting `unobtrusive` js into your partial view. This problem I also faced my validation (data annotation validation) are not working in partial view. Then I call unobtrusive js with this code and working fine for me.

Comment: Sure please mark and upvote my solution if it helps you, thanks